# Thymeleaf th:text returns null

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

im trying to do simple data binding using a Model object and displaying the value on a html page using Thymeleaf. The string literal from the th:text shows fine but when i try displaying the value of the attribute i get null.

Thanks in advance.

```
package control;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller

public class Controls {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        // Pass the date to the view
        model.addAttribute("serverDate", LocalDate.now());
        return "index";
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Showing Date</h1>
    <h1 style="color:green;" th:text="'Today is ' + ${serverDate}">Today is Someday.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing I see is that the line in the html template in question seems strange to me. I would think the `th:text` attribute would be specified like `th:text="Today is ${serverDate}"` without the single quotes or the '+'.  But I'd guess that those characters, if they don't actually do something I'm unaware of, would just show up in the final output.  I still wouldn't expect a `null`.

Comment: Try `th:text="${'Today is ' + serverDate}"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i just had the control.java in the wrong package, that's why it wasn't binding properly.